# Detection of Builtin Camera and Virtual Web Cameras in my web application

Tags: javascript, webapi, getusermedia, mediadevices, virtual-webcam

I want to automatically select the default camera (Builtin Camera) of the laptop if users is using any virtual camera. I want to prevent users from using virtual camera in the web application.

I can get list of cameras available in web browser. But I can't detect which one is virtual camera and which is BuiltIn camera.

```
const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
const videoDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === "videoinput");
```

In videoDevices i get all the information of all available cameras (both builtin cameras and virtual cameras).

But the problem is how to detect which is virtual camera and which is builtin Camera.

Comment: There's no way to do this on web application. At best you can check for camera's name and check if it contains string like 'virtual'. But advanced users can change virtual camera's name anyway.